# locally finite family $ \mathcal{A} $

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

Hello I have had problems with this exercise

Let $X$ be a topological space and $ \mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(X) $ a locally finite family such that for any $ A, B \in A $ with $ A \neq B $ and $ \overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset $. Prove that for all $ x \in X $ exists
an open $ U $ such that $ x \in U $ and  $ U $ intersects at most one element of $ \mathcal{A} $

I have managed to prove that there is an open $ U $ such that $ x \in U $ but I have no idea how to prove that this open intersects at most one element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you mean "... with $A\ne B$, **we have** $\overline A\cap \overline B=\emptyset$"? -- Also, the fact that there exists open $U$ with $x\in U$ is more than trivial as $X$ itself is open. Would you mind trying harder?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Spell out the definition of "locally finite".